# Java program unable to connect on Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I've been using neo4j 1.9.3 for the past one week. Unable to connect to neo4j DB through app as getting the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:  org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@913fe2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:280)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.createDb(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:59)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.main(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:42)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@913fe2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:258)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Could not create lock file
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
... 8 more
```

I have my DB_Path

String DB_PATH = `"C:\\Software-Jars\\neo4j-community-1.9.3\\data\\graph.db"`

Answer (score 1):

Either you are running 2 instances of your program, or you need to make sure you have permission to write to that directory. Neo4j created that lock file, and if an instance is already reading/writing that database, then nothing else can.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas,Now this problem is solved.But I got another one exception.                        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/ObjectCodec

Comment: It sounds like a dependency problem. Make sure you are including Jackson, but the 1.9 version. 2.0 they changed their packaging structure and it's no longer `org.codehaus.jackson`